# Clarification on Thread performance processing 1000's of log files

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, executorservice

I am extracting out lines matching a pattern from log files. Hence I allotted each log file to a Runnable object which writes the found pattern lines to a result file. (well synchronised writer methods)

Important snippet under discussion :

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREAD);


for (File eachLogFile : hundredsOfLogFilesArrayObject) {
executor.execute(new RunnableSlavePatternMatcher(eachLogFile));
}
```

**Important Criteria :**

The number of log files could be very few like 20 or for some users the number of logs files could cross 1000. I recorded series of tests in an excel sheet and I am really concerned on the RED marked results. 
 
 1. I assume that if the number of threads created is equal to the number of files to be processed then the processing time would be less, compared to the case when the number of thread is lesser than the number of files to be processed which didn't happen. (please advice me if my understanding is wrong)

Result :

[image: Result]

2. I would like to identify a value for the NUM_THREAD which is efficient for less number of files as well as 1000's of files

Suggest me answer for Question 1 & 2

Thanks !
Chandru

Comment: Except for the first row, all your numbers look pretty much the same. I don't see any major issues.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Perhaps its because of the initial property files variables initialisation. Would you please suggest a value for the NUM_THREAD which would be good for any case (be it 10 file or 1000 file ? is it a good idea to have 500 as the value)

Comment: The optimal number is highly context-dependent: what number of cores you have, how much each thread spends waiting for I/O operations, how much is the reading of one file slowed down by reads of other files (disk seek time), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just found that your program is not CPU bound but (likely) IO bound

this means that beyond 10 threads the OS can't keep up with the requested reads of all the thread that want their data and more threads are waiting for the next block of data at a time

also because writing the output is synchronized across all threads that may even be the biggest bottle neck in your program, (producer-consumer solution may be the answer here to minimize the time threads are waiting to output)

the optimal number of threads depends on how fast you can read the files (the faster you can read the more threads are useful),

Answer (score 2):

It appears that 2 threads is enough to use all your processing power.  Most likely you have two cores and hyper threading.

> Mine is a Intel i5 2.4GHz 4CPU  8GB Ram . Is this detail helpful ?

Depending on the model, this has 2 cores and hyper-threading.

> I assume that if the number of threads created is equal to the number of files to be processed then the processing time would be less,

This will maximise the overhead, but wont give you more cores than you have already.

Comment: I tried to use 2 threads to process 40 files and the total time = 170 seconds <br>
I used 20 threads to process 40 files and the total time = 145 seconds and saved 25 seconds <br> I am now very much confused on setting the value for NUM_THREAD which is suitable for all number of files . 10's to 1000's

Comment: No need to be confused. Like I said, if you use more than 2 threads, you are getting increasing amounts of overhead and it is slower.

Answer (score 1):

When parallelizing, using a lot more threads than you have available cpu cores will usually increase the overall time. You system will spend some overhead time switching from thread to thread on one cpu core instead of having it executing the tasks at once, one after an other.

If you have 8 cpu cores on your computer, you might observe some improvement using 8/9/10 threads instead of using only 1 while using 20+ threads will actually be less efficient.

Comment: OP is using blocking I/O, which usually means waiting on blocking calls. The balance is not so simple.

Comment: I know, but it seems that in this case, it spends quite a lot of time processing the data. Otherwise using 1 or more threads would pretty much remain the same.

Comment: Mine is a Intel i5 2.4GHz 4CPU <br> 8GB Ram . Is this detail helpful ?

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that I/O doesn't parallelize well, especially if you have a non-SSD, since sequential reads (what happens when one thread reads a file) are much faster than random reads (when the read head has to jump around between different files read by several threads). I would guess you could speed up the program by reading the files from the thread sending the jobs to the executor:

```
for (File file : hundredsOfLogFilesArrayObject) {
    byte[] fileContents = readContentsOfFile(file);
    executor.execute(new RunnableSlavePatternMatcher(fileContents));
}
```

As for the optimal thread count, that depends.

If your app is I/O bound (which is quite possible if you're not doing extremely heavy processing of the contents), a single worker thread which can process the file contents while the original thread reads the next file will probably suffice.

If you're CPU bound, you probably don't want many more threads than you've got cores:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(
    Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
```

Although, if your threads get suspended a lot (waiting for synchronization locks, or something), you may get better result with more threads. Or if you've got other CPU-munching activitities going on, you may want fewer threads.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using cached thread pool.

```
public static ExecutorService newCachedThreadPool()
```

Creates a thread pool that creates new threads as needed, but will reuse previously constructed threads when they are available. These pools will typically improve the performance of programs that execute many short-lived asynchronous tasks. Calls to execute will reuse previously constructed threads if available.

You can read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)

Comment: That will potentially create a *ton* of threads regardless of what the optimum number of threads may be.